# Adding data from one Postgresql server into another Postgresql server using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm pretty new to python and postgresql in general but I'm having problems transferring data from one server into another. Currently I have code to run where I pull data and set that to a variable IT, when I try inserting IT into another Postgresql server, I run into errors.

First I used:

```
cur = con.cursor()
#Connect cursor to local server
IT = DataPull()
#Pulls the data from the remote Postgresql server and set it equal to IT

command2 = (
    """
    INSERT INTO gr_data.it (column_name1,column_name2,column_name3,column_name4,column_name5,column_name6,column_name7) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    """)
cur.execute(command2, IT)
```

But I end up getting the error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ","
LINE 2:...column_name4,column_name5,column_name6,column_name7 VALUES<?,?,?,?,?....
                                                                      ^
```

So I figured it had to do with the question marks, I googled around and found that maybe they should be changed to "%s". Then I received this error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you should perform the insert using variables:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)", (100, "abc'def"))
```

It is taken from official docs you can find [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html)